# Как можно сделать проверку на роль на другом сервере Discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Хочу сделать бота, который будет проверять на наличие роли на другом сервере, и, если есть роль, то он будет выдавать роль на основном сервере.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Только если твой бот будет и на том сервере, на котором хочешь проверять.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Но как это можно реализовать в коде ?